# The high OS version validation detected when copy the database

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have an application that copies the database from the local package to the local folder. After I create the app package to the store and test using Windows App Cert Kit, an error message will appear as shown below:
[image: failed message]

And after I try to install using powershell, then when the application is first opened, the application runs smoothly. But after the application is closed, then run again, then only the splash screen appears.
Code:

```
public static string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Tryout.sqlite"));
if (!CheckFileExists("Tryout.sqlite").Result)
            {
                CopyDatabase();
            }
public async void CopyDatabase()
        {
            StorageFile dbFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Tryout.sqlite"));
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            await dbFile.CopyAsync(localFolder, "Tryout.sqlite");
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Here the [project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U-zFClfEL06nz17j8)

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, the problem is you have used `async` in `App` constructor method, this will cause thread blocking. For checking file exist, you could use `File.Exists` `sync` method to avoid thread blocking. I have edit your code please check.

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    if (!CheckFileExists("Tryout.sqlite"))
    {
        CopyDatabase();
    }

}

private bool CheckFileExists(string fileName)
{
    bool isExist;
    isExist = File.Exists(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,fileName)) ? true : false;
    return isExist;
}
```

Comment: Is the copydatabase () method still using async?

Comment: copydatabase () is  async void, so it could invoke in sync method.

Comment: File.Exists does not throw exception in any circumstance, even if passing an invalid path, or the caller does not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: Yep, the Exists method should not be used for path validation, this method merely checks if the file specified in path exists. Passing an invalid path to Exists returns false. I have remove try catch.

Comment: i got error message: A SQLite Wrapper assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the current project references both SQLitePCL and the following platform-specific assembly: SQLitePCL.Ext. when open the database

Comment: This error looks like the `SQLitePCL` has not been installed successfully, please check this nuget package.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I successfully installed SQLitePCL 3.8.7.2 on the nuget package and it has a clean solution, but the same error message still appears when reading data on sqlite. This only happens when running the application in release mode (if debug mode, the application runs smoothly and no error message appears)

Comment: I have run your demo release mode, it works well. it does not throw any error. Could share which nuget package you have install?